# Can anyone identify this dark grey remote control and receiver with yellow and orange buttons?

Tags: part-identification, remote-control, battery

Does anybody have an idea where this remote control and receiver are originally from:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Bionicle [manas](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?id=4713#T=I) set 8539.
Top [part](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=23323c01&idColor=10#T=C&C=10) from your foto. [Bottom](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=23335c01&idColor=10#T=C&C=10) one.